# What is the meaning of バキン?

Tags: meaning, manga, onomatopoeia

In 亜人 manga I've found the word `バキン`, at least it seems to me so (look at the picture), but I've only found the translation of the word `バキッ baki (crack)` and `パキン pakin (also crack)`. But on the picture I see `ン`, not `ッ` and `バ`, not `パ`.

Is there a difference between those two words, if no why it's written in the book with ン, but in the sources - ッ.

[image]

> [image]
>
> [image: enter preformatted text here]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each onomatopoeia has a lot of variations, and unique ones are created fairly often. It's impossible for a glossary to list them all. The sound of a gunshot is represented like バン, バーン, バキューン, パン, パーン, ドン, ドーン, ズドン, ズドーン, ズガン, ズガーン, and so on and on. バキン is perhaps relatively uncommon, but it's still perfectly understandable.

In this case, you can break バキン into two and understand them separately:

- バ (ba) represents a short explosive sound. It's bigger than パ (pa; typically the sound of a pistol).
- キン/キーン/キューン represents a high-frequency sound (metallic or wind noise)